# Why do we need <h:body> in JSF

Tags: html, jsf-2

Is there any especial purpose of `<h:body>`? `<body>` is not enough while making JSF application?

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_body.html)

> This tag renders an HTML body element. It also provides a target for JSF resource relocation. This enables JSF developers to implement components that have dependencies on resources such as images, scripts, and cascading stylesheets in a more flexible way by telling the JSF framework where to render these resources at request time. The usual targets are the "head" or "body" tags. Relocatable resources are especially useful when implementing JSF2 composite components.

And [this](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/docs/2.0/vdldocs/facelets/h/body.html)

> Render the starting  element tag. Just before rendering the closing  element tag, render any resources that have been targeted for this "body" element:
>
> - Obtain a UIViewRoot instance.
> - Obtain a List of component resources targeted for this "body" element with a call to UIViewRoot.getComponentResources() with the String "body" as the argument. Render the ending  element tag.
> - Iterate over the returned List of UIComponent instances and call encodeAll on each UIComponent instance.

So, I guess the key is in providing resources that JSF framework uses.

The first quote says that *the usual targets are the "head" or "body" tags*. If, for example, in `<h:body>` tag you have `<h:outputScript name="hello.js"/>`, this will render the script in `<body>` tag, but this can be changed to `<head>` if you specify so in `target` attribute. This is Resource Relocation, and can be found explained in more details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gjgep/index.html).

Comment: This "dependencies on resources such as images, scripts, and cascading stylesheets" is DONE in the `<h:head>` tag. Isn't it? If I am wrong then please give me an example and update your answer. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope this makes it more clear.